# Can't attach mousedown event to embed element

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I seem to have hit a wall with this crap and can't make sense of it. I have a page with a relatively complex SVG (it has 6 other smalled SVGs embedded into it) in it embeded inside `embed` tag. When I try to attach a `mousedown` event to it, it simply doesn't work. Here is the markup:

```
<body>
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="images/cog.svg" id="cog">
</embed>
</body>
```

then in javascript I do

```
$(function(){  
  var cog = document.getElementById("cog");
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

It doesn't work. Moreover when i attach events to `document`, they do not fire when I click on that embed object either!
I searched this thing for 3 hours and everywhere I look it appears as if the embed should support `mousedown` even without any problem. What is the problem here?
Edit:
If it's any help here is how the full markup looks like (I use Foundation framework):
[image]

Comment: what does console say?

Comment: Works for me, no need for jQuery - http://jsbin.com/bosaqadebe/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Console doesn't say anything. It simply doesn't attach the event.

Comment: @Marius I think it will only work if the `embed` element stays empty (i.e no `src` set or `src` referring to nowhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) aren't an issue, you can try :

```
document.querySelector('embed').addEventListener('load', function(){
    this.getSVGDocument().addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
        alert('hello')});
        });
```

According to [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-embed-element-setup-steps):

> 3 . If the previous step determined that the content's type is
>   `image/svg+xml`, then run the following substeps:
>
> 1. If the [**embed**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-embed-element) element is not associated with a [nested browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#nested-browsing-context), associate the element with a newly created [nested browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#nested-browsing-context),[...]
> 2. [Navigate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#navigate) the nested browsing context to the fetched resource, with [replacement enabled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#replacement-enabled), and with the [**embed**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-embed-element) element's [node document](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-document)'s
>      [browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#browsing-context) as the [source browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#source-browsing-context). (The [**src**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-embed-src) attribute of
>      the [**embed**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-embed-element) element doesn't get updated if the browsing context gets
>      further navigated to other locations.)
> 3. The [**embed**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-embed-element) element now [represents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#represents) its associated [nested browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#nested-browsing-context).

But I can't find anything about actually how it should handle events.

Nevertheless, it appears that when its `src` is set and returns something, the events are captured by the new context (whether reached or created).

See [@Marius comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448391/cant-attach-mousedown-event-to-embed-element/29449202#comment-47063822) for a demo when no src is set, it fires the event.

Comment: This appears to have done something (at least the event is being triggered), however it is being triggered on the entire square block shape, whereas my SVG image is circular and I don't want users to click empty space and still have the app think they clicked the image. Is there a way to improve this method such that is behaves like in normal document? Sorry if the answer is in the specs, they are written so badly it's incomprehensible to someone new to the topic. If there is no way to improve it, I will accept this answer.

Comment: The `getSVGElement()` method of the `use` element returns the document of the inner svg. From there, you can use any DOM method you like to access your svg elements (like `getElementById` or `querySelector`...)

Answer (score 1):

I think the embed tag is sandboxed and can't be accessed from external sources. Just use the `img` tag.

```js
$('#logo').click(function() {
  alert('410');
});
```

```css
img{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Click the SVG</h3>
<img id='logo' src="http://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg">
```

Comment: I can't, I have tried to. The SVG has other SVGs embedded into it via svg `image` tags and those don't display when I use `img` tag to load the main svg. Is there no way at all to do this?

Comment: I don't think so but I am not certain. I have very little experience with SVGs.